# How do I get an access token from OKTA?

Tags: java, okta-api

I managed to get a session token, but I believe I need to get an access token instead in order to start querying data from the server.  How do I convert this in Java?

I believe I'm looking for the /oauth2/default/v1/authorize equivalent in the okta-authn-sdk-api.jar libraries but I don't see it.  I'm looking for an example of this being done somewhere but I cannot find one.

Comment: Have you checked relevant guides from Okta? https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/redirect-authentication/

Comment: Authentication API, which is what that SDK covers, for some reason does not contain authorization and retrieval of access token. It's kind of confusing. Generally when I needed to get access token from java I just manually constructed the HTTP call - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144721/how-to-get-access-token-using-client-credentials-using-java-code for instance.